# Properties.db Schema or Data Dictionary details

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We have a need to use the sql lite database "properties.db" that can be downloaded with conversion to forge format.

I tried to find documentation on how the tables link and the various field types and how they translate but so far haven't found anything.

Am able to access and read the db with sql queries without any issue. Also linking of tables can be guessed but there are a number of byte[] fields and not sure how to decode or how used.

Does anyone know if there is a db schema? Examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the ProperyDB is only for Autodesk internal usage, so there is no any documentation about the schema. However, you can use any SQLite tool to open it and read data from. For example, http://sqlitebrowser.org/.

Comment: Ok, I had noticed that it has been mentioned in previous forge posts as an option for mass processing of object attributes but if schema is not available thats ok. Thanks for the information.